# Как убрать редирект при неверном вводе email в комментариях wp

Tags: php, wordpress

При неверном вводе мыла, имени или пустом комменте происходит редирект на /wp-comments-post.php
где окно с выводом ошибки

> ОШИБКА: пожалуйста, заполните необходимые поля (имя, e-mail).

Есть ли возможность после валидации полей выводить пусть даже эту ошибку аяксом?
Или уже на крайний случай вообще удалить фильтры трех полей не затронув остального функционала?

Comment: Можно, надо смотреть в коде, где проиходит редирект

Comment: Редирект происходит в файле ядра, а его как раз трогать и не хочется
Шаловливые ручки хотят обновляться по каждому чиху

Answer (score 0):

Вот какой получился костылик.

```
function add_comment_fields($fields) {


$fields['custom_validation'] = "<script>" . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "var comment_form_error = true;" . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= 'if(comment_form_error){ ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "   document.getElementById('commentform').onsubmit = function(){" . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       var $email = jQuery("#email"), $author = jQuery("#author"), $comment = jQuery("#comment"), reg =  /^\w+@\w+\.\w{2,4}$/i;' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       comment_form_error = false; ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       if($comment.val().length > 0){ ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '           $comment.removeClass("error"); ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       } else { ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '           $comment.addClass("error"); ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '           comment_form_error = true; ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       } ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       if($author.val().length > 0){ ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '           $author.removeClass("error"); ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       } else { ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '           $author.addClass("error"); ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '           comment_form_error = true; ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       } ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       if($email.val().length > 0 && reg.test($email.val())){ ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '           $email.removeClass("error"); ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '       } else { ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '           $email.addClass("error"); ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= '           comment_form_error = true; ' . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "       } " . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "       if(!comment_form_error){" . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "           jQuery( '#commentform' ).submit();" . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "       } " . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "       return false; " . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "   } " . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "}" . PHP_EOL;
$fields['custom_validation'] .= "</script>" . PHP_EOL;

return $fields;
```

}

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','add_comment_fields');

Принцип действия довольно прост: Добавляем скрипт, как кастомное поле. Изначально ошибка в состоянии True, пробегаемся по полям проверяем их на заполненность. В случае отсутствия ошибок сабмитим форму по новой. Варианты без флага comment_form_error и 
`$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {event.prventDefault()});` 
почему то не сработали. Видимо мой .онсабмит вызывается раньше дефолтного ВП-листнера.